# How to disable elasticsearch 5.0 authentication?

Tags: authentication, elasticsearch

I'm just start to use *elasticsearch*. Created an index with default settings (5 shards, 1 replica). I then indexed ~13G text files with the *attachment* plugin. As a result, it went very slow searching in Kibana **Discover**. However, searching in the console is fast:

```
GET /mytext/_search
{
  "fields": [ "file.name" ],
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "file.content": "foobar"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "file.content": {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To investigate why it's so slow, I installed *X-Pack*. The guide documentation seems not comprehensive, I didn't get to the security config.

The default install of *elasticsearch* don't have to be logged in, but it have to be logged in after installed *X-Pack* plugin. I'm confused with the security settings of elasticsearch, kibana, x-pack, do they share the user accounts whatever? After all, I get the authentication works by:

```
curl -XPUT -uelastic:changeme 'localhost:9200/_shield/user/elastic/_password' -d '{ "password" : "newpass1" }'
curl -XPUT -uelastic:newpass1 'localhost:9200/_shield/user/kibana/_password' -d '{ "password" : "newpass2" }'
```

Here comes the problem. I can't login using Java client with `org.elasticsearch.plugin:shield`. It's likely the latest version of the shield dependency (2.3.3) mismatched with the elasticsearch dependency (5.0.0-alpha).

Well, can I just disable the authentication?

From the node config:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/_nodes

"nodes" : {
    "v_XmZh7jQCiIMYCG2AFhJg" : {
        "transport_address" : "127.0.0.1:9300",
        "version" : "5.0.0-alpha2",
        "roles" : [ "master", "data", "ingest" ],
        ...
        "settings" : {
            "node" : {
                "name" : "Apache Kid"
            },
            "http" : {
                "type" : "security"
            },
            "transport" : {
                "type" : "security",
                "service" : {
                    "type" : "security"
                }
            },
...
```

So, can I modify these settings, and the possible values are?

Answer (score 122):

In a test environment I added the following option to `elasticsearch.yml`, and/or `kibana.yml`

```
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

Comment: this is the correct answer. source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/security-settings.html

Comment: elasticsearch.yml file is located at /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml

Comment: If using docker-compose, put `- "xpack.security.enabled=false"` under `environment` key in both es and kibana section.

Answer (score 25):

assuming that your image name is elasticsearch. you can use id if you don't like name

if you run docker you can use this. 
go to bash in docker with command

```
docker exec -i -t elasticsearch /bin/bash
```

then remove x-pack

```
elasticsearch-plugin remove x-pack
```

exit docker

```
exit
```

and restart docker image

```
docker restart elasticsearch
```

Disclamer: Solution inspired by 
[Michał Dymel](https://devblog.dymel.pl/2017/05/23/elasticsearch-dev-environment-with-docker/)

Answer (score 13):

When using with docker (in local dev), instead of removing the xpack, you can simply disable it.

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.3
docker run -p 9200:9200 \
    -p 9300:9300 \
    -e "discovery.type=single-node" \
    -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" \
    docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.3
```

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to authenticate using this `xpack_security_enable` equals false but I still getting some authentication errors on my kibana log.

```
elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:1.7.6
    ports:
      - ${PIM_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}:9200
      - 9300:9300
kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.4.1
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: localhost
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://localhost:9200
      XPACK_SECURITY_ENABLED: 'false'
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

This is my current setup, on the kibana I can see some errors:
[KIBANA dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtSYS.png)

On kibana logs I can see:

```
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-06-15T07:43:41Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-06-15T07:43:42Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/"}
```

So it seems it still trying to connect using authentication.

Comment: You can solve Kibana warnings by specifying: `- ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200` under `environment` key in kibana section of your docker.compose file.

Answer (score 0):

I had same xpack issue but with kibana, fixed by following command:

```
docker run docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.5.1 /bin/bash -c 'bin/kibana-plugin remove x-pack ; /usr/local/bin/kibana-docker'
```

so it start container, than removes xpack and after that starts normal process. Same can be done with elasticsearch and logstash.